# Chrome console jumps to sources tab unexpectedly in Codepen

Tags: javascript, codepen

I try to test short lines of code on CodePen while chrome console is open:
[image]

After typing a single word console jumps to the source tab unexpectedly and I can't continue typing anymore?

[image]

I can remember that I've used Codepen without this annoying problem but now it made Codepen useless for me!

How I fix that?

Comment: Does closing and re-opening Chrome solve it? Disable all Chrome extensions and try it? You can try resetting all Chrome settings under Advanced of `chrome://settings/`. Also, just out of curiosity, does the same thing happen with Firefox console?

Comment: None of the above fixed the issue :( What should I do... FF works of course...